# Join Audio and 2 Images Output as Video using FFmpeg and Video should be acceptable by youtube

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg, jpeg

I know this question is similar to the question here [Join Audio and Image -> Output as Video using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/187985/join-audio-and-image-output-as-video-using-ffmpeg), But my requirement is bit more.

I want to join to 2 image files with an audio file to produce a video and this video should be acceptable to load at youtube.

Comment: How would the two images be displayed?  One for the first half and one for the second or what?

Comment: Hi @Paul, yes you can say. I dont mind 2 images or three.

Comment: Does that help? [How to turn images into a video slideshow with sound](http://superuser.com/questions/356974/how-to-turn-images-into-a-video-slideshow-with-sound/356982#356982)